# Как передать массив через post в другой файл php

Tags: php

Есть масссив $places: Array ( [row1] => 1 [seet1] => 5 [row2] => 8 [seet2] => 15 [row3] => 4 [seet3] => 14 )
Как передать данный массив в другой php файл через форму?
Я пытался делать так:

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="places" value="'.$places.'">
<input type="submit" name="booking" value="ЗАБРОНИРОВАТЬ МЕСТО">
</form>
```

И принимать их:

```
$data=$_POST;
if(isset($data['booking'])){
print_r($data['places']);
}
```

Но результат выводит лишь пустой массив. Я пробовал использовать json_encode и json_decode но не получалось.

Comment: покажите код с json_encode и json_decode

Comment: @ArchDemon 
'
$array=json_encode($places); <form action="result.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="places" value="'.$array.'">
<input type="submit" name="booking" value="ЗАБРОНИРОВАТЬ МЕСТО">
</form>
'
и когда получаешь: $array=json_decode($data['places']); print_r($array);

Comment: сделайте `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: `var_export($var)` возвратит массив в виде, в котором PHP сможет его распознать

Comment: @ArchDemon используя `var_dump($_POST['places']);` выводит:string(1) "{"

Comment: @DiD используя `var_export($_POST['places'])` выводит: '{'

Comment: передавать надо разумеется не ферез форму, а через сессию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете с помощью PHP просто так взять и вставить значение таким образом `value="'.$places.'"`. Это нужно делать с помощью `echo`. Более того, таким образом массив таким образом тоже не передать, потому что на выходе будет строка `"Array"`. На помощь приходит функция `json_encode()`. Преобразуя массив в строку, его уже можно будет вставить в качестве значения для поля:

```
<input type="hidden" name="places" value='<?= json_encode($places); ?>'>
```

Обратите внимание, что аттрибут `value` имеет одинарные кавычки. Это связано с тем, что функция `json_encode()` возвращает строку с двойными кавычками и html парсер это воспример как просто фигурную кавычку, а не целую, нужную нам строку.
В файле `result.php` мы с помощью функции `json_decode()` преобразуем нашу строку в объект\массив

**Итого - файл с формой**:

```
<?php  $places = ['row' => 21]; // ваш массив?>
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="places" value='<?= json_encode($places); ?>'>
  <input type="submit" name="booking" value="ЗАБРОНИРОВАТЬ МЕСТО">
</form>
```

**result.php**:

```
<?php
$data=$_POST;
  if(isset($data['booking'])){
    print_r(json_decode($data['places']));
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!  У меня ошибки были видимо из-за кавычек в аттрибуте value